# How to get key of hashtable by value

Tags: c#, key, hashtable

Can i get the key of the hashtable by value. I try to find and code but not success. Anyone can help me.

Thanks somuch

Comment: I have the feeling that you are not using the correct data structure for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: While the question isn't worded well and has few details, there is a distinct, real question here.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [Hashtable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx), the enumerator returned is an [IDictionaryEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionaryenumerator.aspx), which should allow you to do:

```
object key;
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in theHashTable)
{
    if (entry.Value == theValue)
    {
        key = entry.Key;
        break;
    }
}
```

That being said, I would highly recommend a different data structure.  If nothing else, upgrading to using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` will provide type safety, though you will still need to loop through the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue)` items within the Dictionary to find the key matching a value.

Comment: A more compact version would probably be `myHashtable.Where(de => de.Value == theValue).Select(de => de.Key).First()`

Comment: Note that there can be several different keys that all have the same value, so unless you manually ensure that values are unique you won't be able to determine which of the keys corresponds to a particular value.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan That will fail without a `.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` before your `.Where`

Comment: @Servy Very true.  I was just returning the first match.  If all matching keys are required, that could be easily adapted from the above by storing the results in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually loop through the `KeyValuePair<>`s in the dictionary until you find a matching value.

Comment: That would be a dictionnary, not a hashtable (but OP's question does not make sense, so it might as well be that).

Comment: @Cicada: Yes; I was trying to subtly hint that the OP should be using generics.